# Powershell import encoded module

Tags: powershell, encoding, module

I am writing a script with a lot of modules but I don't really want the user to see my source code so I figured to encode everything in base64 since the user won't be able to decode it even if it is that basic.
I tried to somehow add an encoded module but no luck.

So my question is -
Is it possible to import a base64 encoded module to the main script file?

If you have any better solutions to hide source code please share, I would be more than happy to try them out.

P.S. I tried to find some info on making a .dll files but found out I would have to rewrite the script in C#. (if I didn't missed anything)

Also I tried to put all modules into one encoded file, but then the file gets too big and Powershell is not able to process it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options, which can be combined if you would like to be extremely sure that no one will be able to access your code, making your code into an exe was already mentioned, there are several projects to do this but [This one](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/make-ps1exewrapper/) is nice as it is wholly contained within PS.  The other, imo better, method is to use an obfuscator, which will take your code and replace variable names with nonsense strings and make other changes to make your code very difficult to read, it's still possible to work out your code but generally not worth the effort, you can find a working one [Here](http://www.powertheshell.com/powershell-obfuscator/).  But I do have to add that obfuscating your code really goes against the powershell ethos and I recommend against doing it unless you have some sort of requirement too being passed down from management.  And please note that this **NOT** an acceptable method of obscuring code that includes passwords, api keys, or any other information that needs to be secured as all of those are quite easy to extract from code that has been obfuscated this way.

Comment: Thank you, that was a thing I really didn't knew about, I mean the obfuscator. Thank you it helped me to achieve my goal

Comment: Happy to help, keep in mind that you need to keep a non-obfuscated version of your code around if you ever want to make changes, and that it's still possible to work out the logic behind your code, just much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your ps1 to an exe file by using

https://ps2exe.codeplex.com/

You'd still be able to get at the code if you tried, but it would prevent a casual look.

Why do you want to hide the modules?

Comment: Well these are custom modules and contains a lot of logic and functions. So allowing to the user to see those would go against requirements a received. Thank you I'm looking at it now